# Add line break and bold text in response php

Tags: php, symfony

I am returning a ajax response with Symfony2 where I need to split into two lines the content of a message and put some text in bold.The function I am using is:

```
 public function showuserAction()
   {
    $nid=$this->get('request')->request->get('nid');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Users')->findUser($nid);

    if($user){
        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'This NID belongs to the user: '.$user->getName()), 200);
    }
}
```

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: Routing.generate('showuser'),
  data: {dni:dni},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {

    alert(response.message);

  }
 })
```

I hope the following results:

This NID belongs to the user:

**Username formatted in bold**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you send the message and username as separate fields in the returned JSON like this:

```
return new JsonResponse(
    array(
        'message' => 'This NID belongs to the user: ',
        'username' => $user->getName()
    ),
    200
);
```

And then handle how they're formatted on the front-end where the JSON is loaded.

APIs, which is what your JSON response is, should just be about data not what that data should look like, separating these two in your mind when you're coding will help keep your code cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Old plain html tags:

```
return new JsonResponse(
    array(
        'message' => 'This NID belongs to the user<br />: <b>' . $user->getName() . '</b>',
    ),
    200
);
```

As I see you `alert` received message. Message in alert-window cannot be customized. You can try to add `\n` to indicate line break, but adding bold **will not work**.

```
return new JsonResponse(
    array(
        'message' => 'This NID belongs to the user:' . "\n" . $user->getName(),
    ),
    200
);
```

Comment: Hi @u_mulder, I already tried that, and added text labels but does not make the line break.

Comment: Line break is a `<br />` as we have html here. Do you use it? Also show how you output received data.

Comment: Alert window is a standard browser window. You can't customize it. All you can do is add "\n" for line break.

Comment: According. How could add that message in a similar window where you can choose between two options?

Comment: Read about modal windows/popup windows and create'em. There're a lot of templates and styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($user){
        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'This NID belongs to the user: <b>'.$name.'<b/>');, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @SantoshPatel, I already tried that, and added text labels but does not make the line break.

Comment: put <br/> tag where you want.

Comment: `return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'This NID belongs to the user: <br/> '.$user->getName()), 200);` not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jolyonruss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313990/jolyonruss) solution if you want to manage the formatting in JS, or just use pur HTML:

Change the data typ of the AJAX call: `dataType: 'html',`.
Return a simple `Response`:

```
return new Response('This NID belongs to the user:<br><strong>'.$user->getName().'<strong/>');

// or even better
return $this->render('Bundle:Users:showUserPartial.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
```